# Google Script Separate Folders and Subfolders

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm a beginner coder and am using code I found on the internet to create a list of all folders and subfolders from a Google Drive folder. I'm able to generate that list, but I have two issues:

How do I increase the run speed? I keep hitting the max of 6 minutes for executing a function.

How can I tell the difference between a folder and subfolder? I can run the code and see the list of folders, but I would like a way to differentiate between what is a primary folder and what are the secondary folders within that folder before looking at a new one.

I appreciate any help I can get.

Heres the code I'm using

```
function listFolderContents() {
  var foldername = 'name of folder';
  var folderlisting = 'listing of folder ' + foldername;  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(folderlisting);
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername)
  var folder = folders.next();                  
  //listFilesInFolder(folder, sheet);
  traverseFolder(folder, sheet);
};

function traverseFolder(folder, sheet) { 
  listFilesInFolder(folder, sheet);  
  var subFolders = folder.getFolders();
  while (subFolders.hasNext()) {
    traverseFolder(subFolders.next(), sheet);
  }
}

function listFilesInFolder(folder, sheet) {
  var foldername = folder.getName();
  var contents = folder.getFiles();  
  sheet.appendRow( [foldername] );    
  while(contents.hasNext()) {
    var file = contents.next();   
  } 
}
```

Comment: Almost every folder is a subfolder, except for the Drive root folder and any folders you manually removed from the drive root. Further, everything in Drive may be referenced from multiple folders, not just one (Team Drive has the more standard filesystem layout restriction), so a folder could be a direct child of the root yet also a subfolder of some other folder.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified. So I have one primary folder I am pulling names from and within that folder there are 43 primary subfolders where the rest of the data and folders are within those folders. What I would like to know is if there is a way to label or bold the 43 primary subfolders so I can see all the folders within one of the primary subfolders and then when the next one starts.      Ex.) PF1, sub 1, sub 2, sub 3, etc. PF2, sub 1, sub 2, sub 3, etc. PF3, sub 1, sub 2, sub 3, etc. all the way until 43.